# CSS3 selector attribute+class

Tags: html, css

I don't understand because if I have this css rule:

```
.glyphicon-star {
    font-size: 55px;
    color: #FF7F02;
}

span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: gray;

}
```

and I have a span with class .glyphicon.glyphicon-star ... my rule will be applied not only in this span element but in everywhere in my page.

```
<body>
        <div>
            <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Newest</h2>


  <article>
    <div id="crud1" class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                ChartLine 1
            </h3>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
              No-picture 
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-8">
            Description: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

            </div>

        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>



  <article>
    <div id="crud1" class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                ChartLine 2
            </h3>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
              No-picture 
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-8">
            Description: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

            </div>

        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>



  <article>
    <div id="crud1" class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Chart 3
            </h3>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
              No-picture 
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-8">
            Description: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

            </div>

        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>



  <article>
    <div id="c3-1" class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                ChartLine C3
            </h3>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <img src="/assets/img/pen_tomato.png"> 
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-8">
            Description: Chart with round for prisma
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

            </div>

        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>



  <article>
    <div id="c3-3" class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                ChartLine C3
            </h3>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
              No-picture 
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-8">
            Description: Chart without axes
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

            </div>

        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>



  <article>
    <div id="c3-2" class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                ChartLine C3
            </h3>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
              No-picture 
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-8">
            Description: Chart with Date for prisma
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

            </div>

        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>



  <article>
    <div id="chr3" class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Stacked Area Chart
            </h3>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
              No-picture 
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-8">
            Description: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

            </div>

        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>



        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Recently Updated</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Ordered</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if I delete the rule and I add the rule directly in-line in the code I can achieve my goal. (obviously I have to delete the general css rule )

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:gray;">
                </div>
```

Comment: maybe because you forgot to close the span element

Comment: No, I tried it but the result is completely the same

Comment: @SilvioS. make sure your page isn't cached. I can't replicate this issue after adding in the closing `span` tag with the code you've provided.

Comment: @James, I tried it on different browsers. I added  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> is it all right ? Anyway I'm using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your whole page its hard to give you an exact answer. Might it be that somewhere up the DOM Tree is an element that has got the same classes?

Mind a few other things aswell:

Your `<span>` tag isn't closed... might affect the rest of your page.

Inline styles (like `style="color: gray"`) will always overrule all other styles in a stylesheet (unless you use the ugly `!important` rule).

Applying a style to `span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star` will affect a span that has both `glyphicon` class and `.glyphicon-star` class.
Using `span.glyphicon .glyphicon-star` (with whitespace) will affect a child element with class `.glyphicon-star` thta is inside a `<span>` with class `.glyhpicon`.

Comment: It was my fault, I used the same class in another piece of my code! Thanks